# What's the next symbol in the sequence below in the picture?

Tags: visual, sequence

I was given this puzzle today and I'm completely stumped on what the missing symbol would be. Does anyone know what it is and can explain how they got it?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The symbols are

> the digits 0 through 9 along with their mirror images
>  [image]

So the missing one would be

> [image]
>  a 4 and its mirror image.

Comment: Ok so what are the numbers in the puzzle now?

Comment: And if its 4, which way should the 4 be written?

Comment: The mismatch between the title, text, and tags, along with your comments, make me think there is much more to this than meets the eye...